# Multiple keys index leads in an PSQLException with Slick, Postgres on a lagom project

Tags: slick, lagom

I have a lagom application and using for the readside a postgres with lagom jdbc.
Tables are created and works fine. After a restart and an already created table with a multiple key index I get always an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "article_number_fulfiller_idx" already exists
```

My table looks like this:

```
class ArticleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ArticleTableData](tag,ArticleTable.TableName) {
    def entityId = column[UUID](ArticleTable.ColEntityId,O.PrimaryKey)
    def articleBaseNumber = column[String](ArticleTable.ColArticleBaseNumber)
    def articleSpecificationNumber = column[Option[String]](ArticleTable.ColArticleSpecificationNumber)
    def fulfillerVendorNumber = column[String](ArticleTable.ColFulfillerVendorNumber)
    def fulfillerName = column[String](ArticleTable.ColFulfillerName)
    def availability = column[String](ArticleTable.ColAvailability)
    def completeArticleNumber = column[String]("complete_article_number")

    def idxKey = index("article_number_fulfiller_idx",(completeArticleNumber,fulfillerVendorNumber),unique = true)

    def * = (entityId,articleBaseNumber,articleSpecificationNumber,fulfillerVendorNumber,fulfillerName,availability,completeArticleNumber) <> ( (ArticleTableData.apply _).tupled, ArticleTableData.unapply )

  }
```

And my build handler is here:

```
override def buildHandler(): ReadSideProcessor.ReadSideHandler[Article.Event] = readSide
    .builder[Article.Event](ArticleTable.TableName+"_offset")
    .setGlobalPrepare(table.schema.createIfNotExists)
    .setEventHandler[ArticleCreated](insert)
    .setEventHandler[DescriptionAdded](_ => DBIOAction.successful(Done) )
    .setEventHandler[DescriptionRemoved](_ => DBIOAction.successful(Done) )
    .build()
```

I updated my sbt to use the latest:
Instead of this

```
lagomScaladslPersistenceJdbc
```

I use now this

```
"com.lightbend.lagom" %% "lagom-scaladsl-persistence-jdbc" % "1.6.2",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2"
```

**The exception is only ONE of the exceptions I got. I have for every multiple key index an exception :(**

Answer (score 0):

Lagom every restart will try to create new tables and indexes. To avoid getting these errors, do not force the creation of indexes and tables, use ***create if not exist***. If slick does not allow to do it, look on native [queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createindex.html).

Comment: That is reason why i used this `table.schema.createIfNotExists`. It is tricky because a single key throws never an exception only the multiple keys.

Comment: The problem is on create if not exists only the table will be treated with this command. ```create table if not exists "fulfiller_user_repository" ("username" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"vendor_number" VARCHAR,"entity_id" UUID NOT NULL)
create unique index "username_entity_unique_idx" on "fulfiller_user_repository" ("username","entity_id")
```

Comment: As I wrote, you need to do the same for index, please see in the documentation that I add in the answer that it is possible to use for index.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about [the slick issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1999).

The [page](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/ReadSideSlick.html) describes that it is useful for dev and test environments.

In this case, you can try to have:

- "create if not exist" query as @vladislav-kievski suggested,
- some of the databases do not support such queries (SQL Server) and you can catch an exception with appropriate error code

I do not recommend to use globalPrepare() for creating tables and indexes. The main difficulty with this approach is table changes. In this case, you need to think about versioning your database scripts (what will you do in case index removing/adding or removing columns?).